# best way to remove specific index from all arrays in a multidimentional array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, multidimensional-array

hi i have multidimensional array in `php` i want to remove an index from every array , my array is like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ProfilePrivacySettingDefaultID] => 1
            [UserType] => 2
            [Type] => 1
            [EntityID] => 0
            [PrivacySettingPublic] => 1
            [PrivacySettingElephantiUser] => 1
            [PrivacySettingFriend] => 1
            [IsValid] => 1
            [CreatedOn] => 1330580809
            [CreatedBy] => 0
            [UpdatedOn] => 0
            [UpdatedBy] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [ProfilePrivacySettingDefaultID] => 2
            [UserType] => 2
            [Type] => 1
            [EntityID] => 0
            [PrivacySettingPublic] => 1
            [PrivacySettingElephantiUser] => 1
            [PrivacySettingFriend] => 1
            [IsValid] => 1
            [CreatedOn] => 1330580809
            [CreatedBy] => 0
            [UpdatedOn] => 0
            [UpdatedBy] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [ProfilePrivacySettingDefaultID] => 3
            [UserType] => 2
            [Type] => 1
            [EntityID] => 0
            [PrivacySettingPublic] => 1
            [PrivacySettingElephantiUser] => 1
            [PrivacySettingFriend] => 1
            [IsValid] => 1
            [CreatedOn] => 1330580809
            [CreatedBy] => 0
            [UpdatedOn] => 0
            [UpdatedBy] => 0
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [ProfilePrivacySettingDefaultID] => 4
            [UserType] => 2
            [Type] => 1
            [EntityID] => 0
            [PrivacySettingPublic] => 1
            [PrivacySettingElephantiUser] => 1
            [PrivacySettingFriend] => 1
            [IsValid] => 1
            [CreatedOn] => 1330580809
            [CreatedBy] => 0
            [UpdatedOn] => 0
            [UpdatedBy] => 0
        )
    );
```

i want index `ProfilePrivacySettingDefaultID` from all arrays , so the final result will be like this

```
  Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [UserType] => 2
                [Type] => 1
                [EntityID] => 0
                [PrivacySettingPublic] => 1
                [PrivacySettingElephantiUser] => 1
                [PrivacySettingFriend] => 1
                [IsValid] => 1
                [CreatedOn] => 1330580809
                [CreatedBy] => 0
                [UpdatedOn] => 0
                [UpdatedBy] => 0
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
            [UserType] => 2
            [Type] => 1
            [EntityID] => 0
            [PrivacySettingPublic] => 1
            [PrivacySettingElephantiUser] => 1
            [PrivacySettingFriend] => 1
            [IsValid] => 1
            [CreatedOn] => 1330580809
            [CreatedBy] => 0
            [UpdatedOn] => 0
            [UpdatedBy] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [UserType] => 2
            [Type] => 1
            [EntityID] => 0
            [PrivacySettingPublic] => 1
            [PrivacySettingElephantiUser] => 1
            [PrivacySettingFriend] => 1
            [IsValid] => 1
            [CreatedOn] => 1330580809
            [CreatedBy] => 0
            [UpdatedOn] => 0
            [UpdatedBy] => 0
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [UserType] => 2
            [Type] => 1
            [EntityID] => 0
            [PrivacySettingPublic] => 1
            [PrivacySettingElephantiUser] => 1
            [PrivacySettingFriend] => 1
            [IsValid] => 1
            [CreatedOn] => 1330580809
            [CreatedBy] => 0
            [UpdatedOn] => 0
            [UpdatedBy] => 0
        )
    );
```

what is the best way to do this , thank you very much..............

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily use [`array_map`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to do this, with [`unset`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) to remove the index. Example:

```
$your_array = array_map(
  function($array) {
     unset($array['ProfilePrivacySettingDefaultID']);
  },
  $your_array
);
```

Comment: why is this voted up AND marked as the accepted answer. it doesnt work. the array needs to be returned otherwise $your_array will just be empty

Answer (score 0):

I would say a foreach would be the most efficient way of doing this.

so either

```
foreach($user_array as $key => $value){
    unset($user_array[$key]['ProfilePrivacySettingDefaultID']);
}
```

or

```
foreach($user_array as &$value){
    unset($value['ProfilePrivacySettingDefaultID']);
}
```

array_map would just be doing a lot more work than is needed and using an anonymous function as your array_map callback is just counter productive.

```
$user_array = array_map(
    function($value){
        unset($value['ProfilePrivacySettingDefaultID']);
        return $value;
    }, $user_array
);

function array_map ( $callback , $array){

    foreach($array as $key => &$value){

        $value = call_user_func( $callback, $value );
        // which is equal to  
        /*function my_callback($value){
            unset($value['ProfilePrivacySettingDefaultID']);
            return $value;          
        }
        $value = my_callback();*/
    }
    return $array;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I would just iterate over the arrays and unset the specific value:

```
foreach($array AS $value){
    unset($value['ProfilePrivacySettingDefaultID']);
}
```

Comment: Same as @Sudhir, you need to pass $value by reference, using &$value.